# Scrollable Utility Not Working on Aura Component in Global Action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, global-actions, scrolling

I've got a Flow being called in a Global Action via a Lightning Aura Component. The Flow and Component are working, but for some reason the scrollable utility isn't. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<!-- Component is initialized -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" /> 
    <div class="slds-docked_container_align-left">
        <div class="slds-scrollable">
            <div class="slds-docked-modal_composer slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-left slds-grid_align-left slds-is-open" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-heading-id-1" aria-describedby="dialog-content-id-1">
                <div class="slds-docked-composer__body">
                    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Style:

```
.THIS .slds-scrollable {
    overflow: auto !important;
}
.THIS .slds-docked-modal-composer {
    max-width: auto;
}
```

Controller:

```
({
    init : function(component) {
        // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
        let flow = component.find("flowData");
        // In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow's Unique Name/API Name
    flow.startFlow("New_Case");
    }
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I solved this issue by adding the "slds-scrollable" property to the "slds-docked-composer__body" class and set a fixed height of 25 rem in the css.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<!-- Component is initialized -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" /> 
    <div class="slds-docked_container_align-left">
        <div class="slds-docked-modal_composer slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-left slds-grid_align-left slds-is-open" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-heading-id-1" aria-describedby="dialog-content-id-1">
            <div class="slds-docked-composer__body slds-scrollable">
                <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Style:

```
.THIS .slds-scrollable {
    overflow: auto !important;
    height: 25rem;
}
.THIS .slds-docked-modal-composer {
    max-width: auto;
}
```